# UserDefaults.standard.Integer doesn't work with a Number (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, xcode, integer, nsuserdefaults, swift5

I save a count in UserDefaults and load it with viewDidAppear

Saving here:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(JSon.runways.count, forKey: "RunwaysCount")
```

and the number is correct during saving as checked through print() function.

then under viewDidAppear I check for this number:

```
        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "RunwaysCount") == nil
        {
            self.viewRunway1.isHidden = true
            self.viewRunway2.isHidden = true

            print("Runways Count == nil")
        }
        else
        {
            let Number = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "RunwaysCount")
            print(Number)
            if Number == 1
            {
                self.viewRunway1.isHidden = false
                self.viewRunway2.isHidden = true

            }
            else if Number == 2
            {
                self.viewRunway1.isHidden = false
                self.viewRunway2.isHidden = false
            }
            else
            {
                print("Error checking number"
            }
        }
```

The number prints as correct one in my console, however it doesn't go through the Number == functions, goes through else every time and prints "Error checking number"

Im using xCode 11 with Swift 5.

Comment: Please try deleting derived data and restart your Xcode. Xcode ->Preferences -> Locations -> Go to Derived data and delete.

Comment: Please tell what is getting printed in the console?

Comment: Console prints correctly, so if set value is 1 or 2, when view appears console prints it 1 or 2. But still goes through the else part

Comment: To be precise console lines are as follow - Line1: “1” Line2: “Error checking number” and same agin for 2 Also the nil function doesn’t work as the else error prints when value is nil

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it with the below:

```
    if let RunwayCount = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "RunwaysCount") as? IntegerLiteralType
    {
        print(RunwayCount)
        if RunwayCount == 1
        {
            self.viewRunway1.isHidden = false
            self.viewRunway2.isHidden = true

            print("Working Integer 1")
        }
        if RunwayCount == 2
        {
            self.viewRunway1.isHidden = false
            self.viewRunway2.isHidden = false
            print("Working Integer 2")
        }
    }
```

Still unclear to me why the previous way didn't work, but this code fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Scalar types like `Int, Double` and `Bool` in `UserDefaults` are designed to return default values (0, 0.0 and false) if there is no key.

You can take advantage of this behavior

```
let runwayCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "RunwaysCount")
print(runwayCount)
switch runwayCount {
    case 0:
        self.viewRunway1.isHidden = true
        self.viewRunway2.isHidden = true
        print("Runways Count == 0")

    case 1:
        self.viewRunway1.isHidden = false
        self.viewRunway2.isHidden = true

    case 2:
        self.viewRunway1.isHidden = false
        self.viewRunway2.isHidden = false

    default:
        print("Error checking number")
    }
}
```